# Set image width to half page width

Tags: html, css, angular

When trying to make the images on my page equal to 50 percent (half the page) it just sets my images equal to half their original size. What i want is to maintain the image widths (100 percent), and make the flexbox boxes that contain each image, equal to 50 percent (half the page). How do I achieve this while maintaining 100 percent of the images?

```css
  * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
    }
    
    .gallery {
      background-color: blue;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .gallery img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="gallery">
      <div *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index;">
        <img src={{image.src}} [style.width.%]="50" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't you manually setting your image width to 50% by the following line `[style.width.%]="50"`?
That's why your image size is equal to half of the original size! Therefore, just don't provide a width for you image with percentage, but rather write the original size of the image in your HTML.

Just remove the inline width from your image, and play with your parent div `flex-basis: 50%; width: 50%;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set the flex-grow: 2 and the div width: 50%

Use the following CSS code:

```
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.gallery > div {
    flex-grow: 2;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; // use this to display responsive image
}
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks. Dont seem to need the flex-grow:2 though. If i wanted to set the   width: 50%;   and  max-width: 50%; in the HTML, rather than the gallery > div in the CSS, how would I do that? So that i can change it via the typescript.

Comment: I believe you can do something like this: `<div *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index;" [ngStyle]="{'width': '50%', 'max-width': '50%'}"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming none of your images are wider than half the viewport, you could set a `width` of `50vw` on the images' parent (not the `.gallery` — the child `<div>` elements).

```
.gallery > div {
  flex-basis: 50vw;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```